# EXtract the AIC value from a list of survival models

Tags: r, statistics, survival-analysis

I have the following list of model

list_model <- list(fit1, fit2, fit.coxph1, fit.coxph2)

fit1 and fit2 have been realized as follows:

```
surv_object <- Surv(time = data$`Last observation (days)`, event = data$Death)
surv_object 
fit1 <- survfit(surv_object ~ Treatment, data = data)
summary(fit1)

fit2 <- survfit(surv_object ~ Treatment + data$`Age (years)_cat`, data = data)
summary(fit2)
```

While the last ones are Cox models:

```
fit.coxph1 <- coxph(surv_object ~ Treatment, 
                   data = data)
fit.coxph1
ggforest(fit.coxph1, data = data)

fit.coxph2 <- coxph(surv_object ~ Treatment + `Age (years)_cat`, 
                   data = data)
fit.coxph2
```

Does anyone know how to extract iteratively the AIC values from them?
thanks

Comment: `broom::glance()` will take the model fit as input return a data frame with the summary statistics, including a `AIC` variable.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately that does not work for the first two models

Comment: Because `survfit.summary()` doesn't return it - see the output of `summary( survfit( Surv(futime, fustat)~1, data=ovarian))`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was wondering why this value is lacking for the model computed with survfit() function. Isn't it always a model that might fit more or less better?

Comment: I'm honestly not familiar with survival models, I'm just observing. I think this question is worth asking at Cross-Validated.